# Dickson polynomials- recurrence relation.

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

I am trying to prove the following recurrence relation for Dickson polynomial:

$D_{n+2}(X,a)=XD_{n+1}(X,a)−aD_n(X,a) \  \text{for} \ n≥0  \ \text{with initial conditions} \  D_0(X,a)=2 \ \text{and} \ D_1(X,a)=X$

For $n=2$ recurrence is true, but I have problems with the second step.

EDIT:
The definition of Dickson polynomial is:
Let $\mathbb{K}$ is field and let $a \in \mathbb{K}$, $n$-th Dickson polynomial $D_n(x,a)$ is \begin{equation}
    D_n(z+a/z,a)=z^n+(a/z)^n.
\end{equation}

Comment: Please state the definition of Dickson polynomial that you are using. There is one in the Wikipedia article [Dickson polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson_polynomial), but for completeness, please include it in the body of your question.

Comment: Can you expand what you have done with $n=2$? It sounds like you are doing it for each $n$ one by one rather than using induction.

Comment: Sure, I used the Dickson polynomial property : $D_2(x,a)=x^2-2a$

Comment: I think your answer is given in Wikipedia [Power sum symmetric polymomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_sum_symmetric_polynomial#Properties) for the case of $k=2$ variables.